# Set value to the table td in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am getting the id of dynamically generated `td`. after getting the id, I am binding some text to that but its not working

```
$(document).on('click','.add-subject-button',function(){     
   var id=$(this).parent('td').attr('id');
   id.text("dummy text");
}
```

Error I am getting is

> `id.text is not a function`

Comment: This `$(this).parent('td').attr('id')` returns a String, and you're trying to to call `text()` function.

Comment: It's unclear, do you want to set the `dummy text` to the `td`'s HTML or change it's id?

Comment: First this is not plain javascript ( as your title suggests ) . Second, your question is very unclear. Do you want to change/add text inside the td , do you want to change the id of the td , or do you want to add some text to the existing id. THird, you should always include a working snippet with your problem

Answer (score 1):

`attr` with a single parameter returns the value as string, and not the modifiable attribute.

If you want to change such value, use this:

```
var id=$(this).parent('td').attr('id', "dummy text");
```

But you wouldn't do that, right? Change the id??

Perhaps you want this then:

```
var id=$(this).parent('td').attr('id');
$("#" + id).text("dummy text");
```

Or simply:

```
$(this).parent('td').text("dummy text");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

```
$(document).on('click', '.add-subject-button', function() {
  $(this).parent('td').text("dummy text");
});
```

No need to get the id when you already have the jQuery object for the respective scope `td`

Comment: I have tried this, but i dont want like that..anyways thank you bro:)

Comment: I just meant that getting attr `id` then getting a jQuery object from that id dynamically is unnecessary when you already have the object available as `$(this).parent('td')`. But, your app requirement might be different. Whatever works for you is ok.